# AngularJS factory $resource return empty array

Tags: javascript, ruby, angularjs

I made an .json with jbuilder and create factory in my service.js:

```js
.factory "ArticlesEntries",
      ["$resource", ($resource) -> $resource "/news_articles/:id", {},
        index: method: "GET", isArray:true , params: action: "index"
        show: method: "GET", params: action: "show"
      ]
```

My controller is:

```js
angular.module('miApp').controller 'ArticlesEntriesCtrl', [
  "$scope","$location", "ArticlesEntries"
  ($scope, $location, ArticlesEntries) ->
    $scope.articles_entries = ArticlesEntries.query()
    console.log(ArticlesEntries.query())
]
```

But when refresh /news_articles nothing happens in the view {{articles_entries.title}} and in console.log return a empty array.

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check in Chrome Developer Tools if the http request is done? Check it in Network tab, and you can show the response to be sure it's an empty array or not.

Comment: Yes, in Network tab have an articles_entries json and the response its not empty, are content inside json parameters. Then is not returning an empty array? I do wrong the query? because otherwise I do not understand why I return [ ]  to make a console.log (ArticlesEntries.query( ) ). Thanks.

Comment: $resource use promises, try with: `ArticlesEntries.query(console.log)` to print the arguments of the callback. Or using promises `ArticlesEntries.query().then(console.log)`